# Google Sheets Split Issue

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheets spreadsheet which contains a column of full names. In separate columns I am currently splitting the names into First Name and Last Name columns. However, some names on the list include a middle initial (i.e. Thomas M. Williams), two first names (i.e. Mary Jane Baumfeld), and/or two last names (i.e. Samantha Jones Wendell). Is there a formula I can use that can parse out which one is which and separate them into solely either First and Last or First, Middle, and Last? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some formulae with the data in column A, first name in B, middle in C and last in D:

First `=left(A1, find(" ",A1))`

Middle `=regexextract(A1," .* ")`

Last `=right(A1,LEN(A1)-len(B1)-len(C1)+1)`